# REST and hosting of WCF service

Tags: wcf, rest, .net-4.0

I am developing a WCF service (VS2010, .NET 4.0).  If in the WCF service I utilise REST type functionality (i.e. decorate my methods with WebGet, etc), since REST heavily leverages the HTTP protocol, am I locked into hosting the WCF service as HTTP - i.e. do I have the option to host as net.tcp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - Yes, unless you want to write your own HTTP stack analog.
Is there any particular need in Tcp?

Comment: I was of the understanding for the purposes of performance (when frequency of request is high), net.tcp was preferred (eg http://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/archive/2009/01/03/creating-high-performance-wcf-services.aspx) - net.tcp also compacts the message out of the box.  With HTTP we can use GZip and/or IIS/HTTP compression but this adds a further layer of complexity - and in general if you're locked into HTTP (because you've coded around REST) you have no other options

Comment: If speed is realy needed, maybe good old rpc will do? You can also throw in some ProtoBuf serialization.